# PYTHON USING PANDAS LIBRARY TO GET RECORD:--

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements, matching

A table in the database containing STATION and CITY. I just want RESPECTIVE STATION for a list of CITY NAME  in python using the panda's library.

df=pd.DataFrame(pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM REGION', conn))
print(df)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUqAy.jpg)

Comment: Can you please add an example of your database/dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
filtered = df[df['CITY'] == 'Paris']['STATION'].item()
```

If is not, you should provide more info

Comment: i had answered before you sent the image hehe i will update

Answer (score 0):

try this
for example

your dataframe is

```
     city  citycode
  0  Karan        68
  1  Rohit        22
  2  Sahil        21
  3  Aryan        24
```

and you want to extract citycode for Karan

```
df.loc[df['city'] == 'Karan']['citycode']
```

should do the trick